# Git - .gitignore Ignores folders throughout repo

Tags: git

Is it possible to have

```
foo/
```

in .gitignore but then not to ignore

```
 bar/foo
```

without adding

```
 !bar/foo
```

to .gitignore

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `/foo/` instead, `/` matches the beginning of the path. From the [gitignore](http://kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitignore.html) manpages:

> A leading slash matches the beginning of the pathname. For example, "/*.c" matches "cat-file.c" but not "mozilla-sha1/sha1.c".